# Use String.Format with local variables C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for quite some time, after researching quite a bit, I have been unable to find something to help me.
This is what I need: I need to be able to use `String.Format` (`{0}`, `{1}`, etc) along with a local variable.

```
string[] lines = { "Never gonna give you up", "Never gonna let you down"};
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\{0}\Desktop\testttt.txt", lines);
```

In the `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()` I need to be able to replace `{0}` with something. (The users file path using `Environment.UserName`)

I have been unsuccessful in doing so and get returned the error

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Text.Encoding'

Comment: `WriteAllLines(String.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Desktop\testttt.txt",Environment.UserName), lines)` ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should be using System.Enviroment to get the users directory instead of trying to build it yourself. If future versions of Windows move the folder, your code breaks. (And before you say that won't happen, it did going from Win2K to Windows 7.)

Comment: Okay, you tried *something*. That something gave an error. But we don't know what you tried, so do you now expect us to make random guesses to figure out what mistake you could have made to give you that particular error?

Comment: You do realize that string.format isn't even in your code right?  Hilarious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, this is not the way to get the path to the desktop directory. Instead, just do this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

Unlike your solution, this will work with folder redirection, remote profiles, as well as with future (and past!) Windows versions. Not to mention that `Environment.Username` isn't necessarily the correct folder name anyway :)

Second,

```
var subdir = "SomeDir";
File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\SomeParent\{0}\MyFile.txt", subdir), lines);
```

You need to actually *call* the `string.Format` method. If you just add another argument to `File.WriteAllLines` itself... well, how would that work? Are you also writing all your methods to accept a formattable string with a variable amount of arguments?

The somewhat cryptic error message is just trying to tell you that there isn't a method overload that fits your arguments - the closest it can get results in the error shown.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] lines = { "Never gonna give you up", "Never gonna let you down"};
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string.format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Desktop\testttt.txt", yourVariable) , lines);
```

Replace yourVariable with your own